# Can I finish a map task early explictly from code in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

There are cases where I need not traverse every input record in a map task. For example I only emit from up to 200 records that satisfy certain conditions in each mapper then it can quit.

Can I do this in hadoop? Can't find a related method in the api doc yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably achieve this by overriding the `run` method in the [Mapper](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.java).

The run method currently looks like:

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    try {
        while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
            map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
        }
    } finally {
        cleanup(context);
    }
}
```

So this is how the standard `map()` method is being called. You could add a counter in there and break out of the while loop once it hits 200.

Comment: Exactly what I need.